# RabbitMQ client in Elm

Tags: rabbitmq, elm

I'm a newbie in Elm-lang and am writing a program that requires the backend to consume messages from rabbit. I was mainly programming using Elixir before and all the other languages I used had open source rabbit clients. I wonder if there is one for Elm since I couldn't find any on github.

If there isn't one, what's the recommendation for solving this problem? Shall I switch to use web-socket or use frontend to get messages? I was also looking into using haskell servant like this but it seems to make things complicated: https://github.com/haskell-servant/example-servant-elm

Comment: Elm still is more a frontend language but the communication with rabbitmq is a backend thing. You can use elixir as your backend service and communicate with elm by http and with rabbit by amqp.

Comment: @KarolSamborski thank you! will try that.

Comment: I’m not familiar with rabbitMq but I noticed there’s a javascript binding to rabbitMq. With that in mind you can you Elm ports, a mechanism that communicate between Elm and the js environment.

Answer (score 0):

This project has probably long since been finished but RabbitMQ can also use the mqtt protocol which is much more widely used by frontend languages and frameworks. Maybe something like this would work:
https://github.com/Jwsonic/elm-mqtt